# Single sign on , Iframe, Session does not work

Tags: c#

Am working on an Single sign on Application, where am logging into one application with framework version 4.5 hosted in windows 2012 server, passing the accesstoken in the url and then using an IFrame, am trying to post the data to my mvc application with .net core 2.0 hosted in Windows 2016 server.

Validating access token through Iframe where am also setting up session data locally and then using the session for the lifetime of the page.

After validating the request in my authcontroller am having a RedirectToAction method and this makes my session empty. Please can anyone help with these

--
my Iframe url - http://ipaddress/Auth/VaildateToken?ssoToken=4234dfgdfg

MVC application where am validating the token and setting session.

```
 public IActionResult VaildateToken(string ssoToken)
    {
        var result = _Service.VaildateAccessToken(ssoToken);
        if (result != null)
        {                             
            SetSession(result);                    
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");                           
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoAccess");
        }
    }

 public void SetSession(Client client)
    {          
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("EmailId", client.EmailId.ToString());        

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", client.UserName.ToString());           
    }
```

The session is setting fine but after redirect to Action result when am checking the session again, it's null.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string EmailId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("EmailId");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailId))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("logout", "Login");
        }
    }
```

and then I see a login page inside iframe. Could you please help, am doubting this could be due to redirect to action or am missing to set session in iframe.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing your code.  We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The two sites were hosted in 2 different OS versions. One in Windows server 2012 and the other in Windows 2016. Lower version did not support session while posting to higher version of OS.

While hosting both the sites in same OS version, the code worked fine.